# How to dump json data in sqlite database ionic

Tags: json, sqlite, ionic-framework

I would like to insert and retrieve JSON data in sqlite ionic which has multiple values. Also I want to display the data in listview.

```js
var query="SELECT * from triptable";
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query,[]).then(function(res) {
  if (res.rows.length>0) {
    console.log("Values are:"+tripData);
    for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
       $scope.login.push({
         tripId:res.rows.item[i].tripId,
         tripReqId:res.rows.item[i].tripReqId,
         tripProjectCode:res.rows.item[i].tripProjectCode,
         tripProjectName:res.rows.item[i].tripProjectName,
         tripTravellerName:res.rows.item[i].tripTravellerName,
         tripStartDate:res.rows.item[i].tripStartDate,
         tripEndDate:res.rows.item[i].tripEndDate,
         tripOriginCity:res.rows.item[i].tripOriginCity,
         tripTrNo:res.rows.item[i].tripTrNo,
         tripDestiCity:res.rows.item[i].tripDestiCity,
         tripFeedBAckProvided:res.rows.item[i].tripFeedBAckProvided,
         tripStatus:res.rows.item[i].tripStatus
       });
    }
  }
  else {
    console.log("No trips found");
  }
 }, function (err) {
     console.error(err);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.stringify to transform their arrangement json data. To then display the data in list

```
$scope.login = JSON.stringify($scope.login);
```

To list

```
<div ng-repeat="log in login">
  {{login.tripId}}
</div>
```

Comment: thank you ver muc i will try this. Can u give any example code for creating,inserting and retrieving JSON data in sqlite ionic. i am new to ionic.

Comment: Not give you that kind of example, the truth is that you can not insert JSON data, you have to pass only the values, as any type of query to a DB